# how to exlude few nod_modules file from ng build --prod (uglifyjs) - In Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-webpack

how to exlude few nod_modules file from ng build --prod (uglifyjs) as uglifyjs try to compress it , but fails to do so.

I tried to do it using tsconfig.json exclude - not working
so trying to do it through webpack.config.js .

Please could anyone help on this

Comment: Why do you want to exclude them? Can you move them into the `devDependencies` array in package.json?

Comment: thanks for reply , it was throwing as issue so wanted to exclude them.But we upgraded application to angular 7 with all package upgrade which fix my core issue so no need to do this exclusion .